# How to pull AWS Lambda container image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to run a Docker container on AWS Lambda.
Specifically I'm following [this official tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-reqs)

I have the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:12

COPY app app.js package.json /var/task/
RUN npm install

CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

But, when I try to build this I get the following error:

```
docker build -t hello-world .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/4 : FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:12
pull access denied for public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.
```

When I login with `docker login` command I still get the same error.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Works fine here. You shouldn't need credentials for Public ECR (you *can* use auth for [specific cases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/public-registries.html)) but if you just want to consume it, remove the existing credentials

```
docker logout public.ecr.aws
```

and then try the build again.

That said, if you still want to make use of the authentication, you need to re-auth as [described in the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/public-registries.html#public-registry-auth)

```
aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws
```

Answer (score 3):

Run the command: `docker logout public.ecr.aws`

Details:
I got the similar error when trying to pull image for sam (Serverless Application Model) as follows:

```
Building codeuri: /Users/Machine1/Documents/tech/sam-demo/sklearn-sam-inference-demo runtime: None metadata: {'Dockerfile': 'Dockerfile', 'DockerContext':           
'/Users/Machine1/Documents/tech/sam-demo/sklearn-sam-inference-demo/app', 'DockerTag': 'python3.9-v1'} architecture: x86_64 functions: InferenceFunction             
Building image for InferenceFunction function                                                                                                                        
Setting DockerBuildArgs: {} for InferenceFunction function                                                                                                           
Step 1/6 : FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

Build Failed
Error: InferenceFunction failed to build: pull access denied for public.ecr.aws/lambda/python, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.
```

As per the official documentation, to resolve this issue, you can either re-authenticate to Amazon ECR Public or you can log your Docker CLI out of the Amazon ECR Public registry and re-attempt your unauthenticated image pull.

```bash
docker logout public.ecr.aws
```